# Git - how to fix child branch after parent rebase

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Currently  I have 3 branches: master, develop and feature/x

I did rebase develop on master. It took me several hours to finish it, several hundreds of commits... All for a nice history of commits :)

What would be the quickest way to give feature/x (which was previously based on develop) the same history as develop? feature/x has some changes and still holds the old overcomplicated commit history. There's no need to keep any of the new commits made on feature/x, they can be squashed to one.

What I basically need is

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature/y
```

then somehow apply

```
git diff develop..feature/x
```

on top of feature/y. No idea if git supports anything similar. After that I can just override feature/x with feature/y.

Any idea on how to apply that diff or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to squash the diffs in the `feature/x` branch to a single commit this will work:

```
# create a new branch identical to 'develop'
git checkout -b tmp develop
# make the working tree identical to the 'feature/x' branch
git diff HEAD feature/x | git apply -
# add any new files that were added to the 'feature/x' branch
git add foo/bar baz.txt
# commit
git commit -a -m 'Rebase feature/x on develop'
# rename the feature branch
# (or just delete it, you can get it back from 'git reflog')
git branch -m feature/x feature/x.old
# rename the 'tmp' branch to 'feature/x'
git branch -m tmp feature/x
```

Now `feature/x` has identical history to `develop` and is ahead of it by one commit.

Comment: I did have to exclude the binary files due to "error: cannot apply binary patch to 'xxx/file.png' without full index line" and resolve issues with them manually, but everything else went smoothly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `git cherry-pick`

Assuming you've squashed anything from your feature branch into one commit, while one the feature/y branch just do a

```
git cherry-pick thecommithash
```

And that should do the trick.

You can keep multiple commits by a cherry-picking them one by one.

Comment: Better solution if you don't have many commits. In my case, accepted answer was an much easier solution. git diff returned over 1k changed lines, cherry-picking different commits for these would have been a pain. Not sure if those could have been squashed to one commit without a similar approach as in the accepted answer.